# Are there any widely used wrappers/API's for MySQL in python?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm a PHP guy trying out Python with cherryPy. Whenever I work with PHP I use my own simmple wrapper for mysql functions in a form of a class to make things easier to maintain. There is also PDO layer that is widely used but I never really used it in any of my projects. Do people building applications in Python using microframeworks use any kind of wrappers for MySQL instead of straight-out MySQLdb library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) is a common choice. It can also be used as a ORM.

Comment: I prefer writing pure SQL, does SQLAlchemy let you do that?

Comment: Uh... well... yes, but if you're going to do that then you may as well just use MySQLdb directly.

Comment: True... does SQLAlchemy automatically clean/escape data coming from user input?

Comment: That's already covered by DB-API; there's no need to add another layer for that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Will there be any significant performance difference due to additional processing done by SQL Alchemy or a custom written simple wrapper over MySQLdb . If my intent is to only do simple raw sql. Or is SQL Alchemy fast enough even with all its batteries,which I may not use at all.